# What's the anime about a redhead whose friend uses magic?

Tags: zetsuen-no-tempest

I was watching an anime and closed out of it, and now can't get back to it.

Description of the anime: A redhead male lead whose friend learns magic to find the killer of his sister, who was secretly the girlfriend of the redhead male lead.

I was only 3 episodes in on Crunchyroll, so I can't describe it any more. Does anyone know the name of this anime?

Comment: It sounds like you're describing Zetsuen no Tempest, except that the lead (Takigawa Yoshino) is brown-haired. I think Crunchyroll translates the title as "Blast of Tempest".

Comment: @user2245: Remember that you can accept the correct answer by clicking on the large tick mark under the answer's score. See the [help center](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) for more details.

Answer (score 10):

The anime you're talking about is **Zetsuen no Tempest** (or [**Blast of Tempest**](http://www.crunchyroll.com/blast-of-tempest), as Crunchyroll translates it).

It begins with TAKIGAWA Yoshino meeting his long-time friend FUWA Mahiro, who has gained magic powers from KUSARIBE Hakaze (a magician stranded on an island in the middle of nowhere) as part of a deal in which Hakaze will help Mahiro figure out who killed his sister, FUWA Aika. Unbeknownst to Mahiro, Yoshino and Aika were lovers. Drama unfolds thereafter.